# Jena ConversionException while viewing owl:NamedIndividual as an OntClass

Tags: jena, ontology, owl

I am getting the following Jena Named Individual Exception:

```
Cannot convert node http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#NamedIndividual 
to OntClass: it does not have rdf:type owl:Class or equivalent
```

I am unable to find some relevant answer to my problem. Is is due to OWL 2 incompatibility with OWL 1. What are the mitigation strategies available to me?

Comment: In what circumstance is this arising?  I don't think this has to do with Jena's OWL2 support, but rather that for in trying to convert some resource `x` to an `OntClass`, Jena looks for a `x rdf:type owl:Class` triple.  `owl:NamedIndividual` is an `rdfs:class`, and is used in the [serialization](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/REC-owl2-mapping-to-rdf-20121211/) of OWL ontologies, but it's _not_ an `owl:Class`.  Can you explain _why_ some code is trying to convert `owl:NamedIndividual` to an `OntClass`?  It may be trying to do that actually shouldn't work.

Comment: Ian Dickinson's comments reveal that I was mistaken about this;  Jena actually does permit more things than OWL classes (e.g., `rdfs:Class`es) to be viewed as `OntClass`es.  Even though `owl:NamedIndividual` isn't an `owl:Class`, it is an `rdfs:Class`, so the conversion failure _is_ due to a lack of OWL2 support.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, Jena doesn't support OWL2 at the moment. However, you can just call `setStrictMode(false)` on your `OntModel`, and it will allow you to view that resource as a class by switching off strict checking.

Comment: I don't think this stems from OWL2 incompatibility though;  `owl:NamedIndividual` would be used in the [serialization](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/REC-owl2-mapping-to-rdf-20121211/) of an OWL ontology, but is not an `owl:Class`, so shouldn't normally arise as an `OntClass`, either.

Comment: No, owl:NamedIndividual is a class (see http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-quick-reference/#Individuals_.26_Literals), since a resource can be of `rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual`. It's perfectly proper for users to want to see an `OntClass` representation of that.

Comment: Yes, it's an `rdfs:class`, but not an `owl:Class`, unless I'm missing something in that spec (entirely possible, though).  So, assuming that the OP's `OntModel` is based on an OWL OntModelSpec, and not an RDFS one, then `OntClass`es should only correspond to `owl:Class`es, right?  Thus the OP's error that [owl:NamedIndividual  rdf:type **owl:Class**] isn't in the ontology, even though [owl:NamedIndividual rdf:type **rdfs:Class**] is true.

Comment: Jena has always been fairly liberal in this respect. If a resource has `rdf:type rdfs:Class` in an `OntModel`, you should be able to see the `OntClass` facet of that resource. `OntClass` is not making a *semantic* claim about the resource, it is merely providing convenience API - such as having an easy way of listing the subclasses. In my view, it would be reasonable to see the `OntClass` facet of the `owl:NamedIndividual` resource; the fact that it doesn't work is down to OWL2 constants not being tested for in the strict-mode check.

Comment: I didn't realize Jena was so permissive.  This produces some strange, in my opinion, results.  E.g., listing the instances of `owl:Class` as an `OntClass` causes lots of conversion errors;  e.g., `owl:Thing` can't be converted to an `Individual`.  I guess this permissiveness makes sense for OWL Full, but it surprises me in OWL DL.  I see where it's permitted in `OWLDLProfile.java` though;  the `doCheck` for `OntClass.class` permits `RDFS.Class`, `RDFS.Datatype`, and any `RDFS.domain` or `RDFS.range` of a property.

Comment: I think this has reached the natural limit for a StackOverflow comment thread. Please feel free to raise this on Jena dev or users list where we can debate it properly.

Comment: Agreed.  I don't really have any issue with the implementation;  I was just surprised.  I've sent a message to the list and, for the sake of anyone interested in this topic, here's the [permalink](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/jena-users/201307.mbox/%3CCA+Q4Jn=Q+cueuXoeH3zXv+CQifBjA333++RfKN0uVXeBwbhVhQ@mail.gmail.com%3E).